2002 Dodge Ram 1500, no start condition
I have a 2002 Dodge Ram 1500 with 4.7 V 8 and automatic transmission.
No start condition, cranks good, no ECM Codes, scanner show engine RPM do be normal. Fuel is present and it will not start with starting fuel.
Spark looks weak and erratic, like the Shot Down Relay is doing something strange, change the relay and not much difference, even tried to by pass the relay, still no luck. would appreciate some ideas

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair :o)
